Why a network interface still responding even when it is down?
It may sound a bit silly. I'm experimenting with my dn42 network setup, in which I assigned an IP address to a dummy interface of Machine A and connect to another node (Machine B) using a WireGuard interface.
And here's my interesting finding: I can ping Machine A from Machine B using the IP address assigned to that dummy interface of Machine A, even after I run IP link set down dummy on Machine A.  And I can run nc listening on that dummy interface's IP address even if it's down, which makes no sense to me. What went wrong? nc listening on the dummy interface when the interface is down

Just a wrong test.
In your invocation, nc isn't bound to an IP address. It's bound to 0.0.0.0:1337. In an nc version you are using -l flag does not have any arguments; the IP address you've put there is just ignored.
You can confirm that with ss -lnpt:
(in one shell)
$ nc -l 172.20.193.66 -p 1337

(in another)
$ ss -lnpt
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port   Process
...
LISTEN  0       1       0.0.0.0:1337        0.0.0.0:*           users:(("nc",pid=1364725,fd=3))
...

Probably your version of nc uses -s flag for this purpose:
$ nc -l -s 172.20.193.66 -p 1337

In that case, it will be correctly bound to the specified IP address. Notice that it is said to be bound to an IP, not "to an interface".
It's also worth noting that the program bound to an IP this way will not be killed once the IP is removed from the system (for whatever reason — interface down, or just ip addr del was executed). But it will stop answering to requests to that address:port, and it will start answering again should the address appear again. You can, say, remove IP to which the program was bound from one interface and assign it to another, and the program will continue to work, if the requests starts to come through another interface to the said IP.
The same you can achieve by enabling non-local bind: you can start a process bound to a not-yet-assigned IP, then assign that IP and process will start serving requests; this is heavily used in high availability scenarios.
P.S. Please, never paste text as images. It's text, always copy and paste it into the question as text, into a code block.

While wrong test might be true, this doesn't seem to answer the "real" question, namely "why does an IP still "work" when the interface it is assigned to is down" -- assuming the IP did not get removed from the system because of that. (Although AFAIK, at least the short answer for that is basically "Linux just works that way".)

In Linux IP isn't really assigned "to an interface", it's rather assigned "to a system"; the interface is basically needed to correctly add a prefix route associated with the address/netmask pair. I was too lazy to examine the local routing table; basically any address which exists in the table is considered "assigned to a system". If an action (like shutting down an interface) doesn't remove the address from that table, it will continue to work.
